# TClientDataSet Missing Data Provider

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

This question does not have any code, but I must ask for help because I can not resolve this issue.  I searched SO for similar questions and found several whose answers did not help me resolve this problem.

I was having trouble creating a TClientDataSet project with my main development pc, so I tried creating a project on my Windows Tablet.  Both pcs are running windows 8.1 with DelphiXE4.

I added a TClientDataSet, a TDataSource and a TDatasetProvider to a new project.
I added 3 fields in FieldDefs at design time, then selected CreateDataset from the popupmenu of TClientDataSet.  The dataset was created just fine so I continued and added a TDBGrid, TDBNavigator, entered some data and saved the TClientDataSet to a file.

The small demo app worked very well with no problems. I can view and enter data, save to a file and load from a file, so I zipped up the project and copied it to my development pc.  I tried running the demo but when LoadFromFile is called a Missing Data provider exception occurs.  I tried deleting the xml file and then tried to recreate the file using the same process I used on the tablet pc and I got the Missing Data provider message again.

In following up on the SO answers I added MidasLib to uses as recommended in several SO answers but that failed to resolve the problem.  I searched for Midas.DLL and found them to be present.

My question: Is it possible that dsnap180.bpl is corrupt or is something else missing from my development pc?  My objective is to be able to create and open a TClientDataset on my development pc.  Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

**EDIT**
Kens Demo

Pas

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
      System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids,
      Vcl.DBGrids, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient;

    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
        DataSource1: TDataSource;
        DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Collection', ftString, 50);
      ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Filename', ftString, 200);
      ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
      ClientDataSet1.Active := True;
      ClientDataSet1.AppendRecord(['General', 'D:\Images\Test.jpg']);
      ClientDataSet1.AppendRecord(['General', 'D:\Images\BeachBall.bmp']);
    end;
end.
```

DFM

```
object Form1: TForm1
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Form1'
      ClientHeight = 299
      ClientWidth = 635
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      OldCreateOrder = False
      OnCreate = FormCreate
      PixelsPerInch = 96
      TextHeight = 13
      object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Width = 635
        Height = 299
        Align = alClient
        DataSource = DataSource1
        TabOrder = 0
        TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
        TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
        TitleFont.Height = -11
        TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
        TitleFont.Style = []
      end
      object ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet
        Aggregates = <>
        Params = <>
        Left = 71
        Top = 35
      end
      object DataSource1: TDataSource
        DataSet = ClientDataSet1
        Left = 116
        Top = 34
      end
    end
```

DPR
    program Project1;

```
uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: If you're editing your q to follow Ken White's suggestion, one extra thing you might do is to add your saved XML data file to your q.  Then we can try to just load it and see what behaviour we get in a zero code project.

Comment: I know this exception if you open/activate the dataset without a created dataset and no filename set.

Comment: I can not add the xml file to the edit because the app never creates the database as that is where the exception occurs,

Comment: Copying/pasting the above into files on my machine, compiling them and running them works perfectly (both in D2007 and XE6), and I can see data in the grid. I'd suspect you have something gone wrong in your Delphi installation somehow.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me perfectly well:

1. Drop a `TClientDataSet`, `TDataSource`, and `TDBGrid` on a blank form. Connect the grid to the datasource, and the datasource to the clientdataset. (Note no `TDataSetProvider`.)
2. Add the following code to the form's `FormCreate` event:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('FirstName', ftString, 20);
     ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('LastName', ftString, 20);
     ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
     ClientDataSet1.Active := True;
     ClientDataSet1.AppendRecord(['John', 'Smith']);
     ClientDataSet1.AppendRecord(['Jane', 'Doe']);
   end;
   ```
3. Run the application:

[image: Image with grid displaying data]

Adding `MidasLib` to the uses clause removes the need to distribute Midas.dll with your application, but it does not affect the dataset provider at all.

Comment: It also might be worth mentioning that using `MidasLib` isn't necessarily the exact same thing, and is known to have some bugs and quirks which aren't there if using the DLL.

Comment: @Jerry: There's a licensing issue with deploying Midas.dll if you're not using a high enough SKU (Pro, for instance, does not include the rights to redistribute it). I've never hit an issue with MidasLib that couldn't be resolved. It's irrelevant to the issue here, however; the only reason I mentioned it at all was to address the OP's mention, to make sure it was clear that it was not related to the problem in the question.

Comment: With your example I get an exception here:
procedure TCustomClientDataSet.InternalCheck(Status: DBResult);

Comment: @Bill: I can't explain that, because I tested the code I posted (in a new empty VCL application) before posting it. I made no changes to any properties, no additions to the uses clause, and did nothing else that isn't described here (other than reduce the size of the form and move the grid to the location seen, in order to make the image smaller when I uploaded it). You see 100% of the code here. Did you try it in a new, blank VCL forms application, or add it to your existing code?  (continued)

Comment: I did exactly what you did, with a new project.

Comment: Then please edit your question to include the text content of your .dfm (right click the form, choose View as Text, and copy/paste that into your question here), as well as the code from the .pas file, so we can reproduce it exactly as well.

Comment: And also copy/paste the source of the form

Comment: Question Edited to include pas file, dfm and dpr.

Comment: @Bill: I can copy/paste the code into files on my machine, open the project, compile and run it, and it works perfectly well. I'd suspect you have a borked installation of Delphi on your system somehow.

Comment: ah... I thought something was strange here.  The sad part is everything else works perfectly.  What is the least painful way of reinstalling or refreshing?

Comment: @Bill: When an exception is part of your problem, PLEASE always give us the exception class and message. In most cases this informations are very important to analyze a problem.

Comment: @Bill: I add my last comment because I want to know if the exception you get with Kens demo code is the same like the one you get with your own code?

Comment: @Ken: I upgraded to XE7 and all the problems I was having with TClientDataset disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Issue looks like 32 bit/64 bit windows target platform. It would work fine if you target 64 bit. It worked just fine for me. 
Otherwise you may need to verify if you are using 32 bit midas dll

Comment: That's not the issue. The same code in my answer works on both 32 and 64 bit platforms. Delphi ships with both versions of the DLL, and using `midaslib` removes the DLL from the equation.